# Making Raspberry Pi GPIO work from an Azure IoT Edge Module

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, node-red, azure-iot-edge

I have a simple example Node-RED project [here on GitHub](https://github.com/kpm-at-hfi/gpio-poc) where I'm attempting to interact with a few GPIO on a Raspberry Pi running Buster. If I run that project directly on the Pi, it works fine. If I run it as a Module by deploying through Azure IoT Edge, I'm unable to interact with the same GPIO, even if I have deployed using these Container Create Options...

```
{
  "HostConfig": {
    "PortBindings": {
      "1880/tcp": [
        {
          "HostPort": "80"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Privileged": true
  }
}
```

...from `/kpmartinhfi/gpio-poc:latest` on Docker Hub, built using `docker buildx build --platform linux/arm/v7 -t kpmartinhfi/gpio-poc:latest . --push`.

The Node-RED editor UI is avialable at :80 on the device, so it's basically working, but attempting to use GPIO gets access/permissions errors:

```
16 Sep 19:21:33 - [info] Starting flows
16 Sep 19:21:33 - [info] Started flows
16 Sep 19:21:33 - [info] [rpi-gpio out:Buzzer (GPIO20)] err: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/@node-red/nodes/core/hardware/nrgpio.py", line 84, in <module>
 :
16 Sep 19:21:33 - [info] [rpi-gpio out:Buzzer (GPIO20)] err:     GPIO.setup(pin,GPIO.OUT)
RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem.  Try running as root!
 :
16 Sep 19:21:33 - [info] [rpi-gpio out:Relay (GPIO26)] err: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/@node-red/nodes/core/hardware/nrgpio.py", line 84, in <module>
    GPIO.setup(pin,GPIO.OUT)
RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem.  Try running as root!
 :
16 Sep 19:21:33 - [info] [rpi-gpio out:Buzzer (GPIO20)] closed
16 Sep 19:21:33 - [info] [rpi-gpio out:Relay (GPIO26)] closed
16 Sep 19:21:33 - [info] [rpi-gpio out:Relay (GPIO16)] err: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/@node-red/nodes/core/hardware/nrgpio.py", line 84, in <module>
 :
16 Sep 19:21:33 - [info] [rpi-gpio out:Relay (GPIO16)] err:     GPIO.setup(pin,GPIO.OUT)
RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem.  Try running as root!
 :
16 Sep 19:21:33 - [info] [rpi-gpio out:Relay (GPIO16)] closed
16 Sep 19:21:36 - [info] [rpi-gpio out:Relay (GPIO16)] out: 0
16 Sep 19:21:36 - [error] [rpi-gpio out:Relay (GPIO16)] nrpgio python command not running
16 Sep 19:21:37 - [info] [rpi-gpio out:Relay (GPIO16)] out: 1
16 Sep 19:21:37 - [error] [rpi-gpio out:Relay (GPIO16)] nrpgio python command not running
```

What's the best way to resolve this that doesn't leave the system in a terribly insecure state?

My attempt at using `Privileged:true` was meant to be a "hack" just to see things working, but I'm suspecting that that's not a good way to go to "production".

I wonder if I need to do something in the `Dockerfile` like add the default Node-RED user to a group with access to GPIO, but since each attempt takes quite a while to try, I thought I'd ask first. :)

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if this will solve your problem exactly, but one of the things you have to do to get access to the RPI's GPIO pins from your IoT Edge module is to bind them to the module.  for example, I wrote a module in python that integrates with the SenseHat accessory for IoT Edge. Like many libraries, it uses the i2c bus to talk to the GPIO pins, so I map those into my container with these "create options"

```
{"HostConfig":{"Binds":["/dev/i2c-1:/dev/i2c-1"],"Privileged":true}}
```

If that doesn't work, depending on how Node-Red accesses the pins, you can also try

```
{"HostConfig":{"Binds":["/dev/gpiomem:/dev/gpiomem"],"Privileged":true}}
```

or (and I think this is the 'share everything" approach)

```
{"HostConfig":{"Binds":["/sys:/sys"],"Privileged":true}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @steve-busby-msft and @hardillb. I have tried both `"Binds":["/dev/gpiomem:/dev/gpiomem"]` and `"Binds":["/sys:/sys"]` in the container's create options with no change in behavior.

I'm wondering if there might be something different in Buster since I'm also not able to do `echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio16/direction` (I get `-bash: /sys/class/gpio/gpio16/direction: No such file or directory` if I do that).

Comment: At @hardillb 's recommendation elsewhere, I have tried setting up `gpiod` and using the gpiod nodes, and if I hardcode the IP address in the node, this does work. I only mention this here to demonstrate that the hardware and Node-RED installation and code _do_ seem to be working and the problem I'm asking about above does seems to be a real problem attempting to access GPIO directly.

Comment: it very well could be something different in Buster, as I'm only done this in raspbian stretch and never had a problem exposing the GPIO pins into a container.  Not sure where to go from here, sorry.